# What are the odds of rolling 3 pairs with six dice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Given a roll of six standard six-side dice, how do you calculate the odds of rolling 3 pairs? This should included non-unique pairs like 2,2,2,2,3,3 or even 5,5,5,5,5,5.

Comment: One approach would be to count the number of ways that three distinct numbers could be rolled on three indistinguishable dice, then find the total number of outcomes in which all of those numbers are matched on the remaining three dice.

Comment: I wrote [a blog post explaining how to calculate this](http://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html); at the bottom is a little form where you can fill in how many dice you have and it will tabulate all the probabilities for you.  [The output for your question is here](http://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/tabulate-dice.cgi?N=6&S=6).  It says that the pattern `AABBCC` appears with probability $1800\over6^6$, `AAAABB` appears with probability $450\over6^6$, and `AAAAAA` appears with probability $6\over6^6$, for a total of ${2256\over6^6}\approx 4.835\%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's split into $3$ cases:

Case 1: All dice show the same number.  There are $6$ ways this can happen.

Case 2: $4$ dice show the same number, and $2$ dice show a different number.  There are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ different ways to choose the $2$ dice that show a different number, and $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways to choose which two numbers appear.  We then multiply by $2$ to choose which number appears $4$ times, and which number appears $2$ times.  Thus there are $15\cdot 15\cdot 2=450$ possible outcomes for Case 2.

Case 3: There are three distinct pairs.  Here, there $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to choose which three numbers appear, and $6!/2^3=90$ ways to arrange them.  So here we have $1800$ possibilities.

Altogether, there are $6^6$ different outcomes, which gives us a probability of:

$$\frac{6+450+1800}{6^6}=\frac{47}{972}\approx.04835$$

It looks like this will happen about once every $21$ throws.